# Is it possible to use bean level validation provided by JSF 2.0 in JSF 1.2

Tags: java, jsf, bean-validation

Is it possible to use bean level validation provided by JSF 2.0 in JSF 1.2 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSF 2.0 has no such thing as bean level validation. Probably you're confusing with [JSR303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) Bean Validation (the [`javax.validation` API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html)). JSR303 is part of Java EE 6. So if you run a Java EE 6 capable container (Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc), then you'll be able to use JSR303, regardless of JSF version. Otherwise you've got to install a JSR303 implementation separately, like [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you want, but [richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) has [`<rich:beanValidator>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_beanValidator.html)

Comment: Cool. Do you know if this can be used with JSR 303 validated beans? The backing implementation is Hibernate validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Id
private int id;

@NotNull(message = "Company id is required")
private int companyId;

@NotNull(message = "Name is required")
private String name;

@NotNull(message = "Device resolution is required")
@Enumerated()
private DeviceResolution deviceResolution;

@NotNull(message = "Device width is required")
private int deviceWidth;

@NotNull(message = "Device height is required")
private int deviceHeight;
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, this is JSR303 and **unrelated** to JSF. You should not confuse bean validation being part of JSF.